# how to create a win app which can interact with a website?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httprequest, httpresponse, winforms-to-web

Hi
I'm trying to write a windows application which can read HTML content of a specific website and fill some data in some input fields and submit the page.
what I did untill now was reading page content from a `WebBrowser` object, navigated to the website.

I know that i need to create some request/response variables and work with them, but I have no good view on what i'm trying to do.
also, my information about `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` is so low...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) is what you're looking for, examples for [read/write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135186/reading-and-posting-to-web-pages-using-c) to [scrape](http://omegacoder.com/?p=111) abound.

WebClient might be simpler for you to implement but in the end is only a wrapper to the above.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i really dont know how to start working with this

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the approach described in the [HttpWebRequest with https in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542024/httpwebrequest-with-https-in-c) thread as a starting point.